# What is the confirm password approach on json schema draft 07?

Tags: jsonschema

AFAIK the `$data` key was removed on the draft 07 of the JSON schema, so I'm wondering how to approach the Confirm Password

I'm using `Newtonsoft JSON Schema Validator` and I have the following schema, but I got the next errors:

**Error:**

[image]

**Error Message**
  [image]

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "definitions": {
    "SignIn": {
      "properties": {
        "Password": {
          "$id": "SignInPassword",
          "maxLength": 15,
          "minLength": 6,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Username": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "format": "email",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "pattern": "^\\+?[1-9]\\d{1,14}$",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Password",
        "Username"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/SignIn"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "ConfirmPassword": {
          "const": {
            "$data": "1/Password"          
          },
          "minLength": 6,
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "ConfirmPassword"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` was never part of JSON Schema.

With pure JSON Schema, you cannot achieve what you are asking.

There was a proposal to add `$data`, and some libraries implemented it, but it was never included in the actual specification.

Comment: Okay, having this in mind... my approach would to make sure both keys have the same constraints... but add a description on ConfirmPassword explaining that its value must be the same as Password... sounds right?

Comment: You can make sure they have the same constraints by referencing the same definition, but you cannot validate they are the same value, using JSON Schema. You'll have to do that as part of your business logic validation.